# Codeigniter performance when using a template systems

Tags: php, performance, codeigniter, templates

I'm still rather new to using CI but I've been playing around with building a modular template system for it and I think I've got the basic's of it down. My question is that the load times seem to be noticable when I use my template system. I was curious if this is common or if perhaps I'm doing something wrong. I know there are many variables with page load times and my site lives on a VPS so it could also just be that whoever I'm sharing resources with is a sucking them up. Could someone who is well versed in CI look over my code and see if there is anything I could do to speed up load times without sacrificing the modular structure?

Thanks

routes.php

```
 $route['default_controller'] = 'pages/load/home';
 $route['test/(:any)'] = 'sandbox/load/$1';
 $route['(:any)'] = 'pages/load/$1';
 $route['404_override'] = '';
```

pages.php

```
class Pages extends CI_Controller {

public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('menulinks_model');
}

public function load($what = 'home'){// Default load
    $array = array();
    //Make sure content exists
    if (!file_exists('application/views/content/'.$what.'.php')){
        // Whoops, we don't have a page for that!
        $page_content = "The page you are looking for does not exist (ERROR 404)";
    }else {
        //Get menu data
        $array['menulinks'] = $this->menulinks_model->getAllMenuLinks();

        //Get page content
        $page_content = $this->load->view('content/'.$what,$array,TRUE);
    }

    //Build Page
    $data = array();
    $data['head'] = $this->load->view('templates/headplate',$array,TRUE);
    $data['scripts'] = $this->load->view('templates/scriptplate',$array,TRUE);
    $data['content'] = $page_content;
    $data['footer'] = $this->load->view('templates/footplate',$array,TRUE);

    //Render page
    $this->load->view('templates/siteplate', $data);
}
```

Comment: What do the templates look like? As in is there a lot of heavy lifting or DB interaction going on in there? Also take a look at the built in Profiler class to help you pinpoint where the slowdown is occuring http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/profiling.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you are building your template system i think is not the best way.
try to use codeigniter helper for creating template systems it is better and optimized.
for example create a helper by the name of template_helper in your codeigniter helper
and insid that helper create functions for:
 hearder template, left template, right template content template, footer template.

example:

```
if(!function_existe('header_template'))
{
    //you can pass as many parameters as you want or without parameters.
    function header_template($var1,$var2)
    {
         $data = array();
         $data['var1'] = $var1;
         $data['var2'] = $var2;
         //your header view
         $this->laod->view('template/header',$data);
    }
}
```

and insid your controller at constructor load your template helper and than
call these functions. header_template, footer_template etc...
i hope this will solve your problem

Comment: What is the advantage to wrapping the call to view() in another function?